# How to find out the address of multiple clients connected to a WCF duplex service?

Tags: wcf

I am currently developing a WCF duplex Service for 2 clients. The first client would be an asp.net webpage which upon receiving a posting, it will send the data over to the service. When the service receives the data, it will then AUTOMATICALLY send it to the second client which is a winform app through the callback channel...

To make it simpler.

1. Asp.net will invoke the wcf
2. The wcf will reside on the iis server, same as the asp.net
3. WCF will require to send a data to the windows form application that is running on a client side. Only 1 instance of this application will be run at a time.

Comment: which addresses do you mean exactly ? plase show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: i think he meant the address of the clients that is connected to him. as he needs to know the address in order to know who to fire the new posting to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service should know *nothing* about the clients attached to it.  Doing so pretty much breaks the intention of WCF.

A better solution might be to have your clients subscribe to "events" that your service can fire off.  Or maybe the client can provide some information in their requests that indicates a service and method to call back to when needed.